# How can I trim leading and trailing white space?

Tags: r, whitespace, trim, removing-whitespace, r-faq

I am having some trouble with leading and trailing white space in a data.frame.

For example, I look at a specific `row` in a `data.frame` based on a certain condition:

```
> myDummy[myDummy$country == c("Austria"),c(1,2,3:7,19)] 



[1] codeHelper     country        dummyLI    dummyLMI       dummyUMI       

[6] dummyHInonOECD dummyHIOECD    dummyOECD      

<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I was wondering why I didn't get the expected output since the country Austria obviously existed in my `data.frame`. After looking through my code history and trying to figure out what went wrong I tried:

```
> myDummy[myDummy$country == c("Austria "),c(1,2,3:7,19)]
   codeHelper  country dummyLI dummyLMI dummyUMI dummyHInonOECD dummyHIOECD
18        AUT Austria        0        0        0              0           1
   dummyOECD
18         1
```

All I have changed in the command is an additional white space after Austria.

Further annoying problems obviously arise. For example, when I like to merge two frames based on the country column. One `data.frame` uses `"Austria "` while the other frame has `"Austria"`. The matching doesn't work.

1. Is there a nice way to 'show' the white space on my screen so that I am aware of the problem?
2. And can I remove the leading and trailing white space in R?

So far I used to write a simple [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) script which removes the whites pace, but it would be nice if I can somehow do it inside R.

Comment: I just saw that `sub()` uses the `Perl` notation as well. Sorry about that. I am going to try to use the function.

But for my first question i don't have a solution yet.

Comment: As hadley pointed it this regex "^\\s+|\\s+$" will identify leading and trailing whitespace. so x <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x) many of R's read functions as have this option: strip.white = FALSE

Answer (score 489, accepted):

Probably the best way is to handle the trailing white spaces when you read your data file. If you use `read.csv` or `read.table` you can set the parameter`strip.white=TRUE`.

If you want to clean strings afterwards you could use one of these functions:

```
# Returns string without leading white space
trim.leading <- function (x)  sub("^\\s+", "", x)

# Returns string without trailing white space
trim.trailing <- function (x) sub("\\s+$", "", x)

# Returns string without leading or trailing white space
trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)
```

To use one of these functions on `myDummy$country`:

```
 myDummy$country <- trim(myDummy$country)
```

---

To 'show' the white space you could use:

```
 paste(myDummy$country)
```

which will show you the strings surrounded by quotation marks (") making white spaces easier to spot.

Comment: As hadley pointed it this regex "^\\s+|\\s+$" will identify leading and trailing whitespace. so x <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x) many of R's read functions as have this option: strip.white = FALSE

Comment: @Jay: Thanks for the hint. I changed the regexps in my answer to use the shorter "\\s" instead of "[ \t]".

Comment: See also `str_trim` in the `stringr` package.

Comment: is there a trim param in read.spss? I tried `trim_values = TRUE` and `trim.factor.names = TRUE` but to no avail...

Comment: FYI: I trimmed all trailing spaces of the entire dataframe using apply: `df_trimmed <- as.data.frame(apply(df,2,function (x) sub("\\s+$", "", x)))`

Comment: Unfortunately, strip.white=TRUE only works on non-quoted strings.

Comment: There is a much easier way to trim whitespace in R 3.2.0. See the next answer!

Comment: Also need to include `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when using `read.csv`, as this won't work on factors. `trimws()` detailed below will work regardless, but by silently converting factor to character. Both useful answers though, thanks!

Answer (score 607):

As of R 3.2.0 a new function was introduced for removing leading/trailing white spaces:

```
trimws()
```

See: *[Remove Leading/Trailing Whitespace](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/trimws.html)*

Comment: It depends on the definition of a best answer. This answer is nice to know of (+1) but in a quick test, it wasnt as fast as some of the alternatives out there.

Comment: doesn't seem to work for multi-line strings, despite `\n` being in the covered character class. `trimws("SELECT\n    blah\n   FROM foo;")` still contains newlines.

Comment: @Jubbles That is the expected behaviour. In the string you pass to trimws there are no leading or trailing white spaces. If you want to remove leading and trailing white spaces from each of the lines in the string, you will first have to split it up. Like this: 
trimws(strsplit("SELECT\n blah\n FROM foo;", "\n")[[1]])

Comment: Although a built-in function for recent versions of R, it does 'just' do a PERL style regex under the hood. I might have expected some fast custom C code to do this. Maybe the `trimws` regex is fast enough. `stringr::str_trim` (based on `stringi`) is also interesting in that it uses a completely independent internationalized string library. You'd think whitespace would be immune from problems with internationalization, but I wonder. I've never seen a comparison of results of native vs `stringr`/`stringi` or any benchmarks.

Comment: For some reason I could not figure out, ``trimws()`` did not remove my leading white spaces, while Bryan's ``trim.strings()`` below (only 1 vote, mine!) did...

Comment: @JackWasey I've added a benchmark - the example might be somewhat simple, but it should give an idea about the performance

Answer (score 96):

To manipulate the white space, use str_trim() in the stringr package.
The package has manual dated Feb 15, 2013 and is in [CRAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)#Packages).
The function can also handle string vectors.

```
install.packages("stringr", dependencies=TRUE)
require(stringr)
example(str_trim)
d4$clean2<-str_trim(d4$V2)
```

(Credit goes to commenter: R. Cotton)

Comment: This solution removed some mutant whitespace that `trimws()` was unable to remove.

Comment: @RichardTelford could you provide an example? Because that might be considered a bug in trimws.

Comment: Thanks for the require(stringr) their documentation or examples did not have this required line of code!

Answer (score 28):

A simple **function** to remove leading and trailing whitespace:

```
trim <- function( x ) {
  gsub("(^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$)", "", x)
}
```

**Usage:**

```
> text = "   foo bar  baz 3 "
> trim(text)
[1] "foo bar  baz 3"
```

Answer (score 13):

Ad 1) To see white spaces you could directly call `print.data.frame` with modified arguments:

```
print(head(iris), quote=TRUE)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width  Species
# 1        "5.1"       "3.5"        "1.4"       "0.2" "setosa"
# 2        "4.9"       "3.0"        "1.4"       "0.2" "setosa"
# 3        "4.7"       "3.2"        "1.3"       "0.2" "setosa"
# 4        "4.6"       "3.1"        "1.5"       "0.2" "setosa"
# 5        "5.0"       "3.6"        "1.4"       "0.2" "setosa"
# 6        "5.4"       "3.9"        "1.7"       "0.4" "setosa"
```

See also `?print.data.frame` for other options.

Answer (score 11):

Use *[grep](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/grep.html)* or *[grepl](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/grep.html)* to find observations with white spaces and *[sub](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/grep.html)* to get rid of them.

```
names<-c("Ganga Din\t", "Shyam Lal", "Bulbul ")
grep("[[:space:]]+$", names)
[1] 1 3
grepl("[[:space:]]+$", names)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
sub("[[:space:]]+$", "", names)
[1] "Ganga Din" "Shyam Lal" "Bulbul"
```

Comment: Or, a little more succinctly, `"^\\s+|\\s+$"`

Comment: Just wanted to point out, that one will have to use `gsub` instead of `sub` with hadley's regexp. With `sub` it will strip trailing whitespace only if there is no leading whitespace...

Comment: Didn't know you could use \s etc. with perl=FALSE. The docs say that POSIX syntax is used in that case, but the syntax accepted is actually a superset defined by the TRE regex library http://laurikari.net/tre/documentation/regex-syntax/

Answer (score 11):

Removing leading and trailing blanks might be achieved through the trim() function from the gdata package as well:

```
require(gdata)
example(trim)
```

Usage example:

```
> trim("   Remove leading and trailing blanks    ")
[1] "Remove leading and trailing blanks"
```

<sub>I'd prefer to add the answer as comment to user56's, but I am yet unable so writing as an independent answer.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Another related problem occurs if you have multiple spaces in between inputs:

```
> a <- "  a string         with lots   of starting, inter   mediate and trailing   whitespace     "
```

You can then easily split this string into "real" tokens using a regular expression to the `split` argument:

```
> strsplit(a, split=" +")
[[1]]
 [1] ""           "a"          "string"     "with"       "lots"
 [6] "of"         "starting,"  "inter"      "mediate"    "and"
[11] "trailing"   "whitespace"
```

Note that if there is a match at the beginning of a (non-empty) string, the first element of the output is ‘""’, but if there is a match at the end of the string, the output is the same as with the match removed.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use the `stri_trim` function from the `stringi` package which defaults to removing leading and trailing whitespace:

```
> x <- c("  leading space","trailing space   ")
> stri_trim(x)
[1] "leading space"  "trailing space"
```

For only removing leading whitespace, use `stri_trim_left`. For only removing trailing whitespace, use `stri_trim_right`. When you want to remove other leading or trailing characters, you have to specify that with `pattern =`.

See also `?stri_trim` for more info.

Answer (score 5):

I created a `trim.strings ()` function to trim leading and/or trailing whitespace as:

```
# Arguments:    x - character vector
#            side - side(s) on which to remove whitespace 
#                   default : "both"
#                   possible values: c("both", "leading", "trailing")

trim.strings <- function(x, side = "both") { 
    if (is.na(match(side, c("both", "leading", "trailing")))) { 
      side <- "both" 
      } 
    if (side == "leading") { 
      sub("^\\s+", "", x)
      } else {
        if (side == "trailing") {
          sub("\\s+$", "", x)
    } else gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)
    } 
}
```

For illustration,

```
a <- c("   ABC123 456    ", " ABC123DEF          ")

# returns string without leading and trailing whitespace
trim.strings(a)
# [1] "ABC123 456" "ABC123DEF" 

# returns string without leading whitespace
trim.strings(a, side = "leading")
# [1] "ABC123 456    "      "ABC123DEF          "

# returns string without trailing whitespace
trim.strings(a, side = "trailing")
# [1] "   ABC123 456" " ABC123DEF"
```

Answer (score 4):

Use dplyr/tidyverse `mutate_all` with `str_trim` to trim the entire data frame:

```
myDummy %>%
  mutate_all(str_trim)
```

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(335)
df <- mtcars %>%
        rownames_to_column("car") %>%
        mutate(car = ifelse(runif(nrow(mtcars)) > 0.4, car, paste0(car, " "))) %>%
        select(car, mpg)

print(head(df), quote = T)
#>                    car    mpg
#> 1         "Mazda RX4 " "21.0"
#> 2      "Mazda RX4 Wag" "21.0"
#> 3        "Datsun 710 " "22.8"
#> 4    "Hornet 4 Drive " "21.4"
#> 5 "Hornet Sportabout " "18.7"
#> 6           "Valiant " "18.1"

df_trim <- df %>%
  mutate_all(str_trim)

print(head(df_trim), quote = T)  
#>                   car    mpg
#> 1         "Mazda RX4"   "21"
#> 2     "Mazda RX4 Wag"   "21"
#> 3        "Datsun 710" "22.8"
#> 4    "Hornet 4 Drive" "21.4"
#> 5 "Hornet Sportabout" "18.7"
#> 6           "Valiant" "18.1"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Removes trailing \r\n in all columns, unlike any other solutions I've seen that claim to work at the data frame level. I can get rid of tons of untidy and inelegant per-column trims.

Answer (score 2):

The best method is [trimws()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/memisc/versions/0.97/topics/trimws).

The following code will apply this function to the entire dataframe.

```
mydataframe<- data.frame(lapply(mydataframe, trimws),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: or `df[] <- lapply(df, trimws)` to be more compact. But it will in both cases coerce columns to character. `df[sapply(df,is.character)] <- lapply(df[sapply(df,is.character)], trimws)` to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
myDummy[myDummy$country == "Austria "] <- "Austria"
```

After this, you'll need to force R not to recognize `"Austria "` as a level. Let's pretend you also have `"USA"` and `"Spain"` as levels:

```
myDummy$country = factor(myDummy$country, levels=c("Austria", "USA", "Spain"))
```

It is a little less intimidating than the highest voted response, but it should still work.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea, since we don't know how many countries/levels the df actually have. Additionally, R would encode the first element of Dummy$Country as "Austria", even if it were "Spain".

Answer (score 1):

Benchmarking of the main approaches in this thread. This is not capturing all weird cases, but so far we are still lacking the example where `str_trim` removes whitespace and `trimws` doesn't ([see Richard Telford's comment to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15007398/7941188)). Doesn't seem to matter - the gsub option seems to be fastest :)

```r
x <- c(" lead", "trail ", " both ", " both and middle ", " _special")
## gsub function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2261149/7941188 
## this is NOT the function from user Bernhard Kausler, which uses 
## a much less concise regex 
gsub_trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)

res <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  gsub = gsub_trim(x),
  ## https://stackoverflow.com/a/30210713/7941188
  trimws = trimws(x),
  ## https://stackoverflow.com/a/15007398/7941188
  str_trim = stringr::str_trim(x),
  times = 10^5
)
res
#> Unit: microseconds
#>      expr    min     lq      mean median       uq       max neval cld
#>      gsub 20.201 22.788  31.43943 24.654  28.4115  5303.741 1e+05 a  
#>    trimws 38.204 41.980  61.92218 44.420  51.1810 40363.860 1e+05  b 
#>  str_trim 88.672 92.347 116.59186 94.542 105.2800 13618.673 1e+05   c
ggplot2::autoplot(res)
```

[image]

```r
sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS Big Sur 10.16
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  stringr_1.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried trim(). It works well with white spaces as well as the '\n'.

```
x = '\n              Harden, J.\n              '

trim(x)
```

Comment: From which package? This function doesn't exist by default.

Comment: Just not a useful answer without providing the package name, @J.Dan