# removing trailing spaces with gsub in R

Tags: r, gsub

Does anyone have a trick to remove trailing spaces on variables with gsub?

Below is a sample of my data.  As you can see, I have both trailing spaces and spaces embedded in the variable.

```
county <- c("mississippi ","mississippi canyon","missoula ",
            "mitchell ","mobile ", "mobile bay")
```

I can use the following logic to remove all spaces, but what I really want is to only move the spaces at the end.

```
county2 <- gsub(" ","",county)
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2261149/1172302

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use an regular expression:

```
 county <- c("mississippi ","mississippi canyon","missoula ",
        "mitchell ","mobile ", "mobile bay")  
 county2 <- gsub(" $","", county, perl=T)
```

`$` stand for the end of your text sequence, therefore only trailing spaces are matched. `perl=T` enables regular expressions for the match pattern.
For more on regular expression see `?regex`.

Comment: @MikeTP: note that this will only work if there is only a single trailing space.  If your `county` vector has an element with multiple trailing spaces, only the last will be removed.

Answer (score 33):

Read `?regex` to get an idea how regular expressions work.

```
gsub("[[:space:]]*$","",county)
```

`[:space:]` is a pre-defined character class that matches space characters in your locale.  `*` says to repeat the match zero or more times and `$` says to match the end of the string.

Comment: @MikeTP Hadly nicely summarized a bunch of common string functions in his package `stringr`.  The one that does this is `str_trim()`.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't need to use the gsub command - the str_trim function is useful for this.

```
    library(stringr)
    county <- c("mississippi ","mississippi canyon","missoula ",
        "mitchell ","mobile ", "mobile bay")
    str_trim(county)
```

Comment: Note that `str_trim` is a nice wrapper for gsub.  I'm not clear on what you mean by "If you don't need to use gsub".

Comment: This will remove any number of spaces at the end of the string, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Above solution can not be generalized. Here is an example:


    a<-" keep business moving"
    str_trim(a) #Does remove trailing space in a single line string

However str_trim() from 'stringr' package works only for a vector of words   and a single line but does not work for multiple lines based on my testing as consistent with source code reference. 

    gsub("[[:space:]]*$","",a) #Does not remove trailing space in my example
    gsub(" $","", a, perl=T) #Does not remove trailing space in my example

Below code works for both term vectors and or multi-line character vectors   which was provided by the reference[1] below. 

    gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$", "", a, perl=T)


#Reference::
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand this, but for me there is only a leading space, not a trailing space?