# What's wrong with this variable in my data frame?

Tags: r

I am running some analysis on different variables within my data frame, and keep running up against the same problem: for some reason, the months in my $MONTH_NAME variable are duplicated (i.e., there are two instances for most, if not all, months).  I can't figure out why, because on the surface they all appear the same.  **Can anybody tell me what is wrong/how to fix it?**

```
dput(combined.weather$MONTH_NAME)
structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 22L, 22L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 13L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 22L, 22L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 13L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 13L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 22L, 22L, 15L, 15L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 23L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 17L, 17L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 11L), .Label = c("April    ", 
"August   ", "December ", "February ", "January  ", "July     ", 
"June     ", "March    ", "May      ", "November ", "September", 
"October  ", "April", "August", "December", "February", "January", 
"July", "June", "March", "May", "November", "October"), class = "factor")
```

Comment: But you stored some if not all of them twice in your array?? Btw, check here: http://mothereff.in/js-variables => variable names starting with a number are invalid ECMAscript5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got whitespaces in your levels.

How to find out?

```
levels(combined.weather$MONTH_NAME)
```

should give you this output

```
 [1] "April    " "August   " "December " "February " "January  " "July "  [7] "June     " "March    " "May      " "November " "September" "October  " [13] "April"     "August"    "December"  "February"  "January"   "July"      [19] "June"      "March"     "May"       "November"  "October"
```

Notice the space between the quotes and last letters of the months.

So let's trim this using gsub and regex.

```
combined.weather$clean.month <-sub("\\s+$", "", combined.weather$MONTH_NAME)
```

Before I recreate on how to remove leading, trailing and both, here's an excellent answer
that tells you how https://stackoverflow.com/a/2261149/2747709

Sometimes it is worth  looking at the output on the console. 
you can also do `table(combined.weather$MONTH_NAME)` and look carefully

Comment: thank you very much!  Does it make sense to replace the data in #MONTH_NAME, as opposed to creating a new variable called $clean.month?

Comment: Never mind: I used "combined.weather$MONTH_NAME <- NULL" to remove the old variable with the bad data.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues
1. Your object is a factor, not a character.
2. You have some names with `"   extra   whitespace   "`

You can see this at the bottom of the `dput`.
The first point is shown in the `class=...` portion,  and the second point in the `.Label=...` portion.

---

Simple fix:

```
 # For (1)
 x <- as.character(x)

 # For (2) 
 x <- gsub("^\\s*|\\s*$, "", x)
```

Comment: Thank you, @Ricardo Saporta.  Can I run your command "as is", or should I add the MONTH_NAME variable to it somewhere?  Also, is it necessary to change it to character?  What is the advantage of that?