# How to remove leading white space

Tags: r, gsub

I'm not familiar with text processing in R and am stuck on how to remove a leading white space in a string.  Here is some code:

```
set.seed(1234)
b <- paste0(sample(c("bbb ", " bbb "), 10, replace = TRUE), rep("ccc ddd", 10))
print(b)

 [1] "bbb ccc ddd"  " bbb ccc ddd" " bbb ccc ddd" " bbb ccc ddd" " bbb ccc ddd"
 [6] " bbb ccc ddd" "bbb ccc ddd"  "bbb ccc ddd"  " bbb ccc ddd" " bbb ccc ddd"
```

I figured out that I can remove trailing white spaces `sub(' +$', '', b)` but changing it to sub`('$+ ', '', b)` doesn't remove the leading white space.  Guessing it is a quick fix...

Comment: I wonder if you tried searching it first...

Comment: Yes, it is duplicate.  Feel free to remove.  @DavidArenburg, yes, I tried searching, which is how I arrived at the reproducible code.  If I used "trim" instead of "remove," I would have got to this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to this question:

[How to trim leading and trailing whitespace in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261079/how-to-trim-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-in-r)

you'll see a very thorough answer on trimming whitespace:   The answer there gives the following functions:

```
trim.leading <- function (x)  sub("^\\s+", "", x)
```

Applying to your data:

```
set.seed(1234)
b <- paste0(sample(c("bbb ", " bbb "), 10, replace = TRUE), rep("ccc ddd", 10))
b

trim.leading(b)

#[1] "bbb ccc ddd" "bbb ccc ddd" "bbb ccc ddd" "bbb ccc ddd" "bbb ccc ddd" "bbb ccc ddd" 
#[8] "bbb ccc ddd" "bbb ccc ddd" "bbb ccc ddd" "bbb ccc ddd"
```

Answer (score 5):

Try `str_trim` from `stringr`.

For the left side

```
> library(stringr)
> str_trim(b, "left")
# [1] "bbb ccc ddd" "bbb ccc ddd" "bbb ccc ddd" "bbb ccc ddd" "bbb ccc ddd"
# [6] "bbb ccc ddd" "bbb ccc ddd" "bbb ccc ddd" "bbb ccc ddd" "bbb ccc ddd"
```

Similarly, `str_trim(b, "right")` for the right side.  And for both sides, its simply  `str_trim(b)`