# How do I extract certain words in my document into a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, text-mining

EDIT: Reproducible example (I hope I'm doing it right):

I went ahead and used `as.character(docs[1])` to create a string, for reproducibility:

`"list(list(content = c(\"Name: Birthdate (MM/DD): Print Date: Student ID: Institution ID: Page:\", \"\", \"MyName MyBirthday 06/16/2015 N1111111 002785 1 of 1\", \"\", \"A string I don't want\", \"\", \"More stuff I don't want\", \"Don't want\", \"\", \"Names of Classes\", \n\"\", \"Class numbers and sections that I don't want\", \"\", \"Current Cumulative\", \"\", \"AHRS (don't want)\", \"12.0 12.0 (no)\", \"\", \"EHRS (WANT THIS)\", \"12.0 12.0\", \"\", \"QHRS (no)\", \"12.0 12.0\", \"\", \"QPTS (no) \", \" (no) 45.900 45.900\", \"\", \"GPA\", \"3.825 3.825\", \"\", \"Spring 2015\", "etc", \"\",  \"End of Graduate Record\", \"\", \"\\f\"), meta = list(author = NULL, datetimestamp = NULL, description = NULL, heading = NULL, id = \"Unofficial June 2015 copy 2.pdf\", language = \"en\", origin = NULL)))"`

All I want out of this mess is the ID Number (which is N1111111 in this example), the semester (Fall 2014 and Spring 2015), the numbers following EHRS (12.0 12.0, each in its own column), and the numbers following GPA (3.825 3.825, each in its own column).

---

I have text data from academic transcripts that needs to put into a dataframe for analysis. I have converted the transcript pdf into text, but now I need certain information in a dataframe. Specifically, I need data in the following columns:

Student ID, Fall 1 Current Hours, Fall 1 Cumulative Hours, Fall 1 Current GPA, Spring 1 Current Hours, Spring 1 Cumulative Hours, Spring 1 Current GPA, Spring 1 Cumulative GPA, Summer 1 Current Hours, Summer 1 Cumulative Hours, Summer 1 Current GPA, Summer 1 Cumulative GPA

etc, for every semester the student remains at the university.

The number of hours comes from EHRS, and cases where no summer courses are listed are treated as 0 current hours, 0 current gpa, and cumulative hours and gpa are the same as for the spring immediately preceding it.

So far, I've converted the pdf to text using the tm library and have the following example transcript:

`docs <- Corpus(DirSource(cname), readerControl=list(reader=readPDF()))`

`inspect(docs[1])`

Student Name MM/YY 06/16/2015 N11111111 002785 1 of 1

Name of University Beginning of Graduate Record

Fall 2014 Name of School
Master of Science Major: Major

Name of Class 1 Name of Class 2 Name of Class 3 Name of Class 4

COURSE+SECTION 3.0 B+ COURSE+SECTION 3.0 A COURSE+SECTION 3.0 A COURSE+SECTION 3.0 A

Current Cumulative

AHRS
12.0 12.0

EHRS
12.0 12.0

QHRS
12.0 12.0

QPTS
45.900 45.900

GPA
3.825 3.825

Spring 2015

Name of School
Master of Science Major: Major

Name of Class 1 Name of Class 2 Name of Class 3

COURSE+SECTION 2.0 A COURSE+SECTION 2.0 A COURSE+SECTION 2.0 A-

Name of Class 4 COURSE+SECTION 2.0 A

Name of Class 5

COURSE+SECTION 2.0 A-

Name of Class 6 COURSE+SECTION 4.0 A

Name of Class 7

COURSE+SECTION 3.0 B+

Name of Class 8

COURSE+SECTION

3.0 A

Current Cumulative

AHRS
20.0 32.0

EHRS
20.0 32.0

QHRS
20.0 32.0

QPTS
76.700 122.600

GPA
3.835 3.831

End of Graduate Record

Comment: You're using the `tm` package, but I actually think `readLines` + `grep` + `strsplit` would be a more appropriate strategy. Either way, you'll need to provide us with a reproducible example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm so new to SO, I attempted to create a reproducible example just now by converting the corpus document into a string. It's messier but at least it's reproducible, hopefully. Apologies if this still isn't quite right.

Comment: `as.character` is not helpful for reproducibility; `dput` would be better. See [how to make a great reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a strategy I use when documents look alike. If documents are EXACTLY the same. You can skip most of the grep() and use direct references (ie, txt[1]) to the location of the information you want to parse.

Extraction Tactics:

- Use `grep` to identify target row. Using anchors `^` or `$` work well.
- Once target row is identified, use `strsplit` to break into elements needed. Repeat last step.
- Use direct references (`txt[1]`) or regex (`txt[grep("GPA",txt)]`) where possible.
- Parse and reformat in whichever manner you please.

readLines

```
txt <- readLines(con=textConnection(
'Student Name MM/YY 06/16/2015 N11111111 002785 1 of 1

Name of University Beginning of Graduate Record

Fall 2014 Name of School Master of Science Major: Major

Name of Class 1 Name of Class 2 Name of Class 3 Name of Class 4

COURSE+SECTION 3.0 B+ COURSE+SECTION 3.0 A COURSE+SECTION 3.0 A COURSE+SECTION 3.0 A

Current Cumulative

AHRS 12.0 12.0

EHRS 12.0 12.0

QHRS 12.0 12.0

QPTS 45.900 45.900

GPA 3.825 3.825

Spring 2015

Name of School Master of Science Major: Major

Name of Class 1 Name of Class 2 Name of Class 3

COURSE+SECTION 2.0 A COURSE+SECTION 2.0 A COURSE+SECTION 2.0 A-

Name of Class 4 COURSE+SECTION 2.0 A

Name of Class 5

COURSE+SECTION 2.0 A-

Name of Class 6 COURSE+SECTION 4.0 A

Name of Class 7

COURSE+SECTION 3.0 B+

Name of Class 8

COURSE+SECTION

3.0 A

Current Cumulative

AHRS 20.0 32.0

EHRS 20.0 32.0

QHRS 20.0 32.0

QPTS 76.700 122.600

GPA 3.835 3.831

End of Graduate Record'))
```

Cleaning

```
# trim of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261079/whitespace-in-r
trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)
txt <- trim(txt)
# Drop empties
txt <- txt[txt != ""]
```

Search and Parse: ID Number

```
id <- strsplit(txt[1], " ")
id <- id[grep("^[N][0-9]",id)] # Starts with N followed by 0-9
```

Search and Parse: GPA

```
gpa <- txt[grep("GPA",txt)]
gpa <- strsplit(gpa, " ")
gpa <- matrix(
  as.numeric(
    t(
      as.data.frame(gpa)
      )[1:2, 2:3]
    ),ncol = 2)
```

... and so on.

Comment: thank you! This mostly works! One question, the first line of id works but the second returns me list(). Doing `id <- id[grep("^[N]",id)]` also returned the empty list. Any tips?

Comment: and one other question, is there a way to automate the readLines function so that I don't have to copy and paste every single document? There are a couple thousand of these, and inspect(docs[2]) is an invalid text argument

Comment: 1. `grep("^[N],id)` returns nothing. 2. You should ask this as a seperate question, with a reproducible example (dummy data is fine).