# How to work with %in% symbol in R?

Tags: r, binary, match

I found out that %in% stands for matching operator, binary (in model formulae: nesting). There are two tables in my workspace. The first table contains

```
> str(GP.drugs)
'data.frame':   4158393 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ SHA     : Factor w/ 10 levels "Q30","Q31","Q32",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ PCT     : Factor w/ 151 levels "5A3","5A4","5A5",..: 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 ...
 $ PRACTICE: Factor w/ 10191 levels "A81001","A81002",..: 344 345 345 345 345 345 345 345 345 345 ...
 $ BNF.CODE: Factor w/ 1731 levels "0101010C0","0101010E0",..: 878 4 9 11 17 22 25 26 27 28 ...
 $ BNF.NAME: Factor w/ 1524 levels "Abacavir                                ",..: 317 289 294 1284 37 379 655 825 1115 824 ...
 $ ITEMS   : int  1 27 1 2 97 4 40 98 27 2 ...
 $ NIC     : num  1.89 74.94 3.2 7.35 439.83 ...
 $ ACT.COST: num  1.77 69.92 2.98 6.84 408.43 ...
 $ PERIOD  : num  201109 201109 201109 201109 201109 ...
```

The second table contains

```
> str(problem.drugs)
'data.frame':   13 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Drug    : Factor w/ 13 levels "Alogliptin","Glipizide",..: 1 2 3 9 10 11 12 13 4 7 ...
 $ Category: Factor w/ 1 level "metformin": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

The code and the error I am using is

```
> t<-subset(GP.drugs,n %in% p)
> t
[1] SHA      PCT      PRACTICE BNF.CODE BNF.NAME ITEMS    NIC      ACT.COST  PERIOD  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

More errors

[image]
[image]

Does it make difference on the tables' column names or does it make it difference on the number of columns both have?

Comment: could you give us an example of the data? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: What happens when you do `any(n %in% p)`?

Comment: You should copy/paste the code into the question rather than upload screenshots. You can format the code by indenting each line with four spaces (a shortcut is to select it and click the `{}` button, [see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks))

Comment: @MhairiMcNeill, I get the same answer and I have updated the question.

Comment: what about if you do `any` though? I think the problem might be that there's just not any `BNF.drugs` matching anything in problem drugs

Comment: @MhairiMcNeill, applying any gives me the same answer.

Comment: does it say `TRUE` or `FALSE`?

Comment: I meant do `any(n %in% p)` on it's own, not in the subset. I'm pretty sure your problem is that nothing matches and I think David Robinson solution will work

Comment: @MhairiMcNeill, it gives me true now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `BNF.NAME` column in the `GP.drugs` data frame appears to have extra trailing spaces in it: notice it says something like `"Abacavir                               "` as the first element. If this is true of all the drugs in `GP.drugs`, but not the ones in `problem.drugs`, it will prevent any from matching.

To fix this, you can use the `str_trim` function from `stringr`, which trims leading and trailing whitespace:

```
library(stringr)
n <- str_trim(GP.drugs$BNF.NAME)

# same thing you did before
p <- problem.drugs$Drug
t <- subset(GP.drugs, n %in% p)
```

[Other solutions can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261079/how-to-trim-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-in-r).

Comment: You are right. I found the error and now it is working perfect. Thank you

Comment: @MhairiMcNeil, Thank you as well .

Comment: ha, I didn't do anything but thanks are accepted anyway!

Comment: FYI, In either R 3.2.0 or 3.2.1 the `trimws` function was added to the `base` package and serves the same purpose of `str_trim`.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
GP.drugs[GP.drugs$BNF.NAME %in% problem.drugs$Drug, ]
```