# R code to select a column with spaces

Tags: r

I am trying to write a simple R code to select multiple columns. I am able to do this when the column names do not have spaces. When it has any space, it doesn't work. Could you please help? I am sure that this is really a simple question. I searched for answers in this forum, but I couldn't find any.

Here is my code.

`df.mydata <-select(df.rawdata, ID, Job, Role ID)`

I get an error. Can you please correct the syntax?

Comment: You prly want ``select(df.rawdata, ID, Job, `Role ID`)``

Comment: I tried both single and double quotes. But its not working. I am using dplyr.

Comment: may be you should check this and avoid the spaces in first place. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261079/how-to-trim-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-in-r

Comment: copy/paste my code - it's not a standard single quote. Dunno what the character is called, though.

Comment: unless you are left-handed, in which case it's just tick :D

Comment: Backtick/tick whatever may be. It works perfectly. :D Thank you all..