# Is there an equivalent of strip() from python in R?

Tags: r

I have some data that was inputed by researchers with unwanted spaces so for example "Sample 1" is inputed as "Sample 1 " and it is messing with my ability to call it a factor. In python I would use strip but I can't seem to find an equivalent R function. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261079/how-to-trim-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`trimws` from the base package may be what you are looking for.

```
samples = c('Sample 1', 'Sample 1 ')
trimws(samples)
[1] "Sample 1" "Sample 1"
```

You can also apply it over a `data.frame`:

```
dat$samples <- trimws(dat$samples)
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted Thank you