# Reading text file with varying column width but fixed delimiter in R

Tags: r, data.table, delimiter, space, read.table

I have multiple .txt files which look like this:

```
header
header
header
header
header
01130009.JPG   JPEG         2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM   G:\AAA AAAAAAAA\AAAAA\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\CAM_07-0008\Farther Downg   Gray Fox                                                                           
01130009.JPG   JPEG         2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM   G:\AAA AAAAAAAA\AAAAA\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\CAM_07-0008\Farther Downg   Direct Register Walk, Gait, Gray Fox, Stop                                         
01130009.JPG   JPEG         2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM   G:\AAA AAAAAAAA\AAAAA\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\CAM_07-0008\Farther Downg   Gray Fox
```

The width of the last 2 columns varies, but there is always 3 spaces between all the columns (3rd column is empty in this case).

I'm using this code to read in the example .txt:

```
read.fwf(filename.txt,skip=5,widths=c(12,16,19,76,83),fill=T,fileEncoding = "UTF-16")
```

But this code won't work properly on this .txt:

```
header
header
header
header
header
01130009.JPG   JPEG         2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM   G:\AAA AAAAAAAA\AAAAA AA\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\CAM_07-0008\Farther DowngBBB   Gray Fox                                                                           
01130009.JPG   JPEG         2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM   G:\AAA AAAAAAAA\AAAAA AA\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\CAM_07-0008\Farther DowngBBB   Direct Register Walk, Gait, Gray Fox, Stop                                         
01130009.JPG   JPEG         2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM   G:\AAA AAAAAAAA\AAAAA AA\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\CAM_07-0008\Farther DowngBBB   Gray Fox
```

Is there a way to read in a .txt file with a fixed deliminator (3 spaces) instead of having to define the width of each column, since the column width varies between files.

The files also have some issues with encoding, so [here](http://dropbox.com/s/5st9k602bcfhzwk/first%20one%20-%20Copy.txt?dl=0) is the example file I'm using

Comment: have you tried with read.table ?

Comment: Yes, I tried read.table(filename.txt,skip=5,sep="   ",fileEncoding="UTF-16") and with sep=" " and sep="" and every time I get an error Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 2 did not have 103 elements

Comment: That is because it separates on any white space, not just the three spaces in a row. If you don't have too many files, an easy solution could be just to replace all occurrences of three spaces in those with tabs, then use the `read.table` call you just tried.

Comment: Are these big files? You could read them all as raw text, replace three spaces with a tab with `gsub` and then parse that as table input. Or are you on a unix-like machine? You can read from a `pipe()` and do that translation quickly with something like `awk`.

Comment: I have hundreds of those files. But they are not too big 50 to 300 lines in each or so.

Comment: I'm not on a unix-like machine, unfortunately

Comment: I have added code for reading files in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there are good tools that look for multi-char delimiters, and you aren't the first to ask about it. Most (incl `read.table`, `read.delim`, and `readr::read_delim`) require a single-byte separator.

One method, though certainly not efficient for large files, is to load them in line-wise and do the splitting yourself.

(Consumable data that the bottom.)

```
x <- readLines(textConnection(file1))
x <- x[x != 'header'] # or x <- x[-(1:5)]
```

(I'm guessing it isn't always the literal `header`, so I'm assuming it's either a fixed count or you can easily "know" which is which.)

```
spl <- strsplit(x, '   ')
str(spl)
# List of 3
#  $ : chr [1:31] "01130009.JPG" "JPEG" "" "" ...
#  $ : chr [1:20] "01130009.JPG" "JPEG" "" "" ...
#  $ : chr [1:7] "01130009.JPG" "JPEG" "" "" ...
```

This seems ok, except that in your examples, there are lots of blanks on the right ...

```
spl[[1]]
#  [1] "01130009.JPG"                                                                
#  [2] "JPEG"                                                                        
#  [3] ""                                                                            
#  [4] ""                                                                            
#  [5] "2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM"                                                         
#  [6] "G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther Downg"
#  [7] "Gray Fox"                                                                    
#  [8] ""                                                                            
#  [9] ""                                                                            
# [10] ""                                                                            
# [11] ""                                                                            
# [12] ""                                                                            
# [13] ""                                                                            
# [14] ""                                                                            
# [15] ""                                                                            
# [16] ""                                                                            
# [17] ""                                                                            
# [18] ""                                                                            
# [19] ""                                                                            
# [20] ""                                                                            
# [21] ""                                                                            
# [22] ""                                                                            
# [23] ""                                                                            
# [24] ""                                                                            
# [25] ""                                                                            
# [26] ""                                                                            
# [27] ""                                                                            
# [28] ""                                                                            
# [29] ""                                                                            
# [30] ""                                                                            
# [31] ""
```

So if you know how many columns there are, then you can easily remove extras:

```
spl <- lapply(spl, `[`, 1:7)
```

and then check the output:

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, spl), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#             V1   V2 V3 V4                  V5
# 1 01130009.JPG JPEG       2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM
# 2 01130009.JPG JPEG       2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM
# 3 01130009.JPG JPEG       2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM
#                                                                             V6
# 1 G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther Downg
# 2 G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther Downg
# 3 G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther Downg
#                                           V7
# 1                                   Gray Fox
# 2 Direct Register Walk, Gait, Gray Fox, Stop
# 3                                   Gray Fox
```

This works equally well with your second example:

```
x <- readLines(textConnection(file2))
x <- x[x != 'header'] # or x <- x[-(1:5)]
spl <- lapply(strsplit(x, '   '), `[`, 1:7)
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, spl), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#             V1   V2 V3 V4                  V5
# 1 01130009.JPG JPEG       2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM
# 2 01130009.JPG JPEG       2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM
# 3 01130009.JPG JPEG       2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM
#                                                                                   V6
# 1 G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA AA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther DowngBBB
# 2 G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA AA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther DowngBBB
# 3 G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA AA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther DowngBBB
#                                           V7
# 1                                   Gray Fox
# 2 Direct Register Walk, Gait, Gray Fox, Stop
# 3                                   Gray Fox
```

Consumable data:

```
# note: replaced single '\' with double '\\' for R string-handling only
file1 <- 'header
header
header
header
header
01130009.JPG   JPEG         2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM   G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther Downg   Gray Fox                                                                           
01130009.JPG   JPEG         2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM   G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther Downg   Direct Register Walk, Gait, Gray Fox, Stop                                         
01130009.JPG   JPEG         2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM   G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther Downg   Gray Fox   '
file2 <- 'header
header
header
header
header
01130009.JPG   JPEG         2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM   G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA AA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther DowngBBB   Gray Fox                                                                           
01130009.JPG   JPEG         2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM   G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA AA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther DowngBBB   Direct Register Walk, Gait, Gray Fox, Stop                                         
01130009.JPG   JPEG         2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM   G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA AA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther DowngBBB   Gray Fox   '
```

Comment: I tried readLines, and there is smth with encoding in those txt files, so when I do readLines I get "ÿþh" ""    "", and readLines doesn't take fileEncoding argument, right? I should fix my example, because this works for the example data

Comment: [`readLines(..., encoding="utf-8")`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readLines.html)?

Comment: No, that doesn't work. I uploaded my txt in dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/5st9k602bcfhzwk/first%20one%20-%20Copy.txt?dl=0

Comment: I don't know command line tools, but I guess if you sub the triple space for a tab before passing to fread, it should work. `library(data.table); library(magrittr); file2 %>% gsub(" {3}(?=[^ ])","\t", ., perl=TRUE) %>% fread(skip=5, fill=TRUE)` Oh, nvm, just noticed the other answer covers it.

Comment: `readLines(file("first one - Copy.txt", encoding='utf-16'))` worked without warning/error.

Comment: If you have issues with performance (due to *many* or *really large* files), you should lean closer to unixy cli tools, such as preprocessing your files (on the command line) with `sed -e "s/   /|/g" files*`. If you have [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) installed, you have `sed` available (somewhere); if not, install it, since you should probably be using version control anyway :-)

Answer (score 2):

One can read the file skipping header rows, then use `gsub` function to replace 3 spaces with a convenient separator (vertical bar used here):

```
> mytext = "01130009.JPG   JPEG         2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM   G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther Downg   Gray Fox
01130009.JPG   JPEG         2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM   G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther Downg   Direct Register Walk, Gait, Gray Fox, Stop
01130009.JPG   JPEG         2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM   G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther Downg   Gray Fox"

> ddf = read.table(text=gsub("   ", "|", mytext), header=F, sep="|")
> ddf 
            V1   V2 V3 V4                  V5                                                                           V6
1 01130009.JPG JPEG NA NA 2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther Downg
2 01130009.JPG JPEG NA NA 2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther Downg
3 01130009.JPG JPEG NA NA 2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther Downg
                                          V7
1                                   Gray Fox
2 Direct Register Walk, Gait, Gray Fox, Stop
3                                   Gray Fox
```

Edit: As suggested by @r2evans in comments below, text has to be trimmed to remove trailing spaces using `gsub(" *$", "", ...)`. Alternatively, following function is from [How to trim leading and trailing whitespace in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261079/how-to-trim-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-in-r):

```
trim.trailing <- function (x) sub("\\s+$", "", x)
```

For text files, one can use readLines to read the text file:

```
> mytext = readLines(file('testfile.txt')) # read file text
> mytext = mytext[-c(1:5)]           # remove first 5 rows ('header')
> mytext = gsub("\\s+$", "", mytext) # remove trailing spaces
> mytext = gsub("   ", "|", mytext)  # change separator
> ddf = read.table(text=mytext, header=F, sep='|') # read columns from text
> ddf
            V1   V2 V3 V4                  V5                                                                           V6
1 01130009.JPG JPEG NA NA 2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther Downg
2 01130009.JPG JPEG NA NA 2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther Downg
3 01130009.JPG JPEG NA NA 2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther Downg
                                          V7
1                                   Gray Fox
2 Direct Register Walk, Gait, Gray Fox, Stop
3                                   Gray Fox
```

Alternatively, one can first read them to a data.frame of one variable, then manipulate the rows to get desired result:

```
> ddf1 = read.table(file='testfile.txt', sep = '\n', skip=5)
> mytext = gsub("\\s+$", "", unlist(ddf1$V1))
> ddf2 = read.table(text=gsub("   ", "|", mytext), header=F, sep='|')
> ddf2
            V1   V2 V3 V4                  V5                                                                           V6
1 01130009.JPG JPEG NA NA 2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther Downg
2 01130009.JPG JPEG NA NA 2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther Downg
3 01130009.JPG JPEG NA NA 2/5/2018 3:53:44 PM G:\\AAA AAAAAAAA\\AAAAA\\BBBB BBBB & BBBBB BBBBB\\CAM_07-0008\\Farther Downg
                                          V7
1                                   Gray Fox
2 Direct Register Walk, Gait, Gray Fox, Stop
3                                   Gray Fox
```

Comment: I think your sample data has removed all of the trailing spaces from the data ... I suspect that whatever created the data files space-filled the rows. Minor, but that means `read.table` will see different numbers of columns in each row.

Comment: (This can probably be mitigated with another `gsub(" *$", "", ...)`.)

Comment: For this to work I'd have to open every single file and do mytext ="...", is there a way to read directly from .txt? I have hundreds of them, and I don't want to open every single one of them

Comment: @Liza If you know a command-line way to correct the delimiter, fread accepts that: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Convenience-features-of-fread

Comment: One can use `read.table` function to read a text file: http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/utils/html/read.table.html